# Where can I download the Oracle 11g client installer for Windows?

Tags: oracleclient

I need to install both 32 and 64 bit client for Oracle 11g but at the following links I can just find the Oracle *instant client*, while I need the *full installer*:
https://www.oracle.com/it/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html
https://www.oracle.com/it/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

E.g.: I can find 11.2.0.4.0 version (*instant client*) but not the previous (11.2.0.3.0), which was available with the *full installer*.

At the moment it seems that Oracle has completely abandoned the full installer (now unavailable on official sites), but still useful for those who need to quickly establish connections between systems (e.g. connected servers, ODBC data sources, etc.)

I hope someone can help me

Comment: edelivery.oracle.com appears to have 11.2 database downloads which should allow you to do a client only install.  I'm not seeing a client-only install but I could well be missing it (and that may change over time).  If you need the client-only install for some reason and you can't find it on edelivery, you can open a support request with Oracle to get it assuming you have a support contract.

Comment: If you need to "quickly establish connections" then Instant Client would seem to be the best option.  What unstated constraints do you have?  Also don't forget that newer Oracle clients will connect to older databases, see https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download it from the [Oracle edevlivery Cloud](https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery)
(*you need an Oracle Account in order to download it*)

It's a bit tricky to find, but you have to search for the Database 11g (11.2.0.4) and when you "check out" you have to choose which software you want to download, just uncheck Database and Clusterware, choose the platform and download your full client

Here's a screenshot from the site

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's very difficult to find a full client installation from Oracle.
Your point to add the Database, Check out and uncheck unwanted items is the key here.  I was searching for "Database Client" on the eDelivery Cloud and was not successful. 
The site is impossible to navigate or find anything on.
Thanks for your answer.